# create multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to populate a multi-dimensional array.  Let's say I have a table of transactions with various billing dates.  First I have an array that retrieves the following 'billed' dates:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [BILLED] => 2011-11-18 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [BILLED] => 2011-11-22 00:00:00
        )

)
```

I also have the following query which is currently hard-coded to one of the two 'billed' dates shown above:

```
$qryOrders = $this->db->query("
       SELECT tblOrders.* 
       FROM tblOrders 
       WHERE tbltc.BILLED = '2011-11-22'"); 
$data['Orders'] = $qryOrders->result_array();
```

I know that I can very easily determine the count of array items by using count($Orders); but how can I instead pass through each of the 'billed' dates of 2011-11-18 and 2011-11-22 to that I can determine the overall count, for both of the specified dates?

I hope I've explained it clearly enough.  I am thinking that I probably need some kind of foreach loop and each time through the loop I could pass in the billed date, and keep track of a running total each time through the loop.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: Is this a question about arrays or about SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure actually.  Should I have mentioned that I am using CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: In other words, you want a count of orders received between two dates? MySQL's COUNT and BETWEEN statements will help.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Actually, that's not what I want.  I don't want a count of items BETWEEN two dates.  I want a count of items on each of the series of dates.  Sometimes 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc.  I must need to iterate through to get my dates, and then run COUNT *foreach* of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
// this is getting all results for a record
$sql = 
<<<sql
SELECT tblOrders.* 
FROM tblOrders 
WHERE tbltc.BILLED between '{$arr[0]}' and '{$arr[1]}'
sql;

// this is to get total count of matched record
// $sql = 'select count(*) from ..';
```

if you are using CI, you can easily using bind

example:-

```
$sql = 'SELECT tblOrders.* FROM tblOrders WHERE tbltc.BILLED between ? AND ?';
$this->db->query($sql, array($arr[0], $arr[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not sure what you mean about using bind?

Comment: CI manual has the example, please refer to the updated answer and http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html (look for query binding)

Comment: I should also add that sometimes I have 2 elements in the date array, sometimes 3 or 4 or 5.  This varies, thus my thinking a loop would be needed.

Comment: this is something I can't help, you have to understand how the BETWEEN  works (start, end). you can do iterate to find the minimum and maximum then bind

Comment: I've read-up on how the BETWEEN works, and it's not what I am looking for.  I need to find an example that will iterate through my records and use the date value each time.  thanks.

Comment: do you mean `GROUP BY`? (group by date)